# How to get last access time of file in PHP

Tags: php

How to get correct last access of files in PHP? I've tried fileatime but it returns few days last access timestamp but I am sure there are many files accessed much more later.
How fileatime take the timestamp, what is taken as "access"?
Should GIT make some troubles? (Is checkout taken as "access" of file?...)

Comment: Plaese show us what you tried

Comment: $somePath = './app/text/file.php';
$lastAccess = fileatime($somePath);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastAccess);

Shows me for example 25.9.2015 11:34:25 but I am sure this file is really very historical and no script can't touch it

Comment: Last access time of what?. is it folder or a file?

Comment: Last access of file. Method fileatime [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) has to shown last access (include, read) of file... but I think there are irelevant results. I want to know why and try to eliminate problems to get correct last access timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two important things to note**

1. The result of fileatime function are cached. Use clearstatcache() to
   clear the cache.
2. Some Unix systems have access time updates disabled, because this
   function reduces performance for applications that regularly
   accesses a large number of files.

So , have a try as following example

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
echo fileatime("test.txt");
echo "<br />";
echo "Last access: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",fileatime("test.txt"));
?>
```

Comment: I loop all files of my application. There are many different timestamps, but last timestamp is cca 1 month (31.8.2015) back... it's some smarty compiled templates, log files,... but I am really sure there must be more files which are not used for months... I think git checkout, pull, could make some troubles... It's on my local repo, maybe on product server it could be ok...

Comment: clearstatcache() works perfect. On product server gets all correct timestamps of files. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last accessed: " . date("F d Y H:i:s.", fileatime($filename));
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add some explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please reffer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

I don't know it will work for files, but I used this for folders.

```
$stat = stat('path_of_dir_or_file');
$timespan= $stat['atime']; // will show unix time stamp.
$time=date('d/m/Y', $timespan);
```

Comment: It's that same as fileatime